# Combining instance-based learning with regression analysis to improve predictions

Tags: regression, prediction, rapidminer

I have a table that contains items. Each day its possible that an incident can occur to some items but equally no incident may happen. I wish to see if its possible to create a prediction for the next day based on the information below

```
**Date      Item 1    Incident       Location**
20130701    40          12           ES
20130702    50           6           ES
20120701    60          10           ES
20120702    20           8           ES
```

This could be a regression problem (at the moment I'm only interested in seeing the next days prediction) but I have an idea that taking the same time period for the previous year and combining it with this years data based on week number (e.g. week 37 this year with week 37 last year) would enrich the prediction because the weather could be similar or the conditions for the incident could be similar. This might make it possible to get a better prediction.

I'm using rapidminer for this but would know if anyone would know how to implement this correctly or even point me to some research papers that may have covered this. I can get up to five years of data so in essence week 37 five times but for the different years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attention conservation notice: this is a long comment.

Sure -- this approach is called instance-based learning and matches current weather patterns to the "best matches" among previously-observed weather conditions; an introduction appears in *Data Mining: Practical Machine Learning Tools and Techniques.*

Your proposal merges matching and an explicit generalization (regression). Some things to consider:
How do you measure similarity to previous instances? I don't know anything about your data, but I suspect there are patterns that have resulted in *different* patterns at subsequent intervals.

A second part of building the model will be considering how to combine/weight the previous instances with the regression forecast to make a prediction. This can be done by simple averaging or more complicated methods like weighting the instances according to *how* similar they are, according to some metric.

I'm not familiar with `rapidminer` so I'm afraid my answer is not complete with respect to your tool-specific advice.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Rapidminer is very good...very simple and a gateway to R..which is what im trying to practice this on. I have purchased the book. It may give me some ideas